# How to shorthand non-commutative multiplication?

Tags: c++, operators, multiplication

Is there a shorthand to writing non-commutative variable multiplication in C++?

For example with commutative variables we can do this:

```cpp
a = a * b;
a *= b;    // same as the above
```

However with non-commutative variables, we can't:

```cpp
a = a * b; // #1
a = b * a; // #2 different than above

a *= b;  // same as #1
// ???   // shorthand to #2?
```

Is it possible to shorthand `#2`?

Comment: Why would you need this? The output of a *= b and a = a * b is the same because of the commutative law. Method #1 would be the shortest which comes to my mind.

Comment: @wpichl and op's asking about `a = b * a;` not a cummulative one. Like matrix multiplication for example - the order matters.

Comment: @wpichl as bloody says. This is specifically a case of matrix multiplication I'm dealing with, to clarify it for anyone who needs further context.

Comment: There is no direct way to do it. Just use textual function names like `mul_left` / `mul_right`.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, there is no way in standard C++.

However when adding a proxy class, it is possible to get the desired syntax:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <array>

template <class T>
class R
{
public:
  R(T& lhs)
    : _lhs(lhs)
  {}
  T& operator *=(const T& rhs)
  {
    _lhs = rhs * _lhs;
    return _lhs;
  }
  T& operator -=(const T& rhs)
  {
    _lhs = rhs - _lhs;
    return _lhs;
  }

private:
  T& _lhs;
};

int main()
{
  int a = 2, b = 5;
  R(a) -= b;
  assert(a == 3);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/9jcqsf)